# bootstrap tooltip is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap in my application. I'm trying to show a table of contents as tooltip using **data-html="true"**. but its not working.

Here is my code:

```
    <div title="<table><tr><td>Column1</td><td>Value1></td><tr><td>Column2</td><td>Value</td></tr></table>" 
       data-html="true" rel="tooltip" style="cursor:pointer;" 
       class="infobox infobox-red  infobox-dark  " onclick="OpenDetails(this)">
      <div class="infobox-icon"><i class="logo-box boa"></i></div>
      <div class="infobox-data"><span class="infobox-data smaller">BOA</span>
      <div class="infobox-content">(0/0/0/0 )</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    $(function () {
            $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
        });    

    function OpenDetails(Obj){
     }
```

Thank you all in advance for your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using

```
data-original-title
```

Html:

```
<div rel='tooltip' data-original-title='<h1>big tooltip</h1>'>Visible text</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip({html:true});
```

Just use the following files if you are going to use all bootstrap functions:

```
-bootstrap.css
-bootstrap.js
```

Answer (score 0):

using

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });
</script>
```

at the end of the body tag (after jQuery and Bootstrap)

---

Aslo use

```
title="Column1 | Column2 <br> Value1 | Value2"
```

instead of

```
title="<table><tr><td>Column1</td><td>Value1></td><tr><td>Column2</td><td>Value</td></tr></table>"
```

the final version could be like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div
      title="Column1 | Column2 <br> Value1 | Value2"
      data-html="true"
      rel="tooltip"
      style="cursor: pointer"
      class="infobox infobox-red infobox-dark"
      onclick="OpenDetails(this)"
    >
      <div class="infobox-icon"><i class="logo-box boa"></i></div>
      <div class="infobox-data">
        <span class="infobox-data smaller">BOA</span>
        <div class="infobox-content">(0/0/0/0 )</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
      });
    </script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```