# Image in Bootstrap Tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to show a **tooltip** with an image in some pages of my website. But, somehow, when I try to use the tooltip from **bootstrap**, only the path to the image is shown and not a tooltip. Can anyone give a hint, what is eventually wrong?

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    html:true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    
<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    
<!-- Latest compiled Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<label class="checkbox">
  @{
    var imageSrc = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/1.jpg");
   }
  <a href="#" data-toogle="tooltip" title="<img src='@imageSrc'/>">
    Style no. 1
  </a>
</label>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bootstrap tooltip is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629855/bootstrap-tooltip-is-not-working)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fix typo (`data-toggle` instead of `data-toogle`) and everything will work:

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    html: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<!-- Latest compiled Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<label class="checkbox">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<img class='img-thumbnail' src='https://picsum.photos/200/100'/>">
    Style no. 1
  </a>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    animated: 'fade',
    placement: 'bottom',
    html: true
});

<a data-toggle="tooltip" title="<img src='http://getbootstrap.com/apple-touch-icon.png'/>">
        <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>
    </a>
```

Also, refer https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-insert-image-inside-bootstrap-popover.php